# Excluding projects from build programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, build, sln-file

Maybe I am overlooking something here but I can't seem to find a good way to parse a solution file and programmatically **exclude** some projects (.vcxproj) from the build. Many SO posts reference the `SolutionFile` class in `Microsoft.Build.Construction` to enumerate the list of projects and their configurations. In fact there is even a `IncludeInBuild` property that tells me if a particular configuration is selected to be included in the build (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.construction.projectconfigurationinsolution.includeinbuild.aspx)

However I can't seem to find a way to *alter*/create-a-copy-of the solution file and do a moral equivalent of setting the IncludeInBuild property to false for some projects.

Is this not possible today?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. It is not very clear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @NightOwl888 What exactly is not clear? That will help me reframe the question. BTW, I haven't tried anything because I haven't seen a way to do this. Basically be able to 1) Open a .sln file 2) Exclude some projects from the build for some configurations 3) Rename and save sln file. I want to be able to do this programmatically.